# NameError: name xxxxxx is not defined in flask

Tags: python, flask, celery

Am having an Import Error issue in a flask restful application, below is the  project structure.

```
project/
   app/
     views/
        tasks.py
        flask_celery.py
   run.py
```

So as you have seen above that's the project structure, so my challenge is am importing a variable from `run.py` to `tasks.py`. But when I run the application I get an error `NameError: name 'celery_access' is not defined`

So this is my run.py file :

```
from app.starwars.star_wars import StarWars
from app.utils.flask_celery import make_celery

app = Flask(__name__)

# configure celery
app.config.update(
    CELERY_BROKER_URL='redis://redis:6379/0',
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='redis://redis:6379/0'
)

celery_access = make_celery(app)

# secret key
app.secret_key = "xxxx"
api = Api(app)
```

Then, in the `tasks.py` file it's where I access the variable name `celery_access`  as below :

```
from run import celery_access

@celery_access.task()
def paginate_requested_data():
    return Hello World''
```

How can I resolve the import ?

Answer (score 0):

Functions from .py file (can (of course) be in different directory) can be simply imported by writing directories first and then the file name without .py extension:

```
from directory_name.file_name import function_name
```

And later be used: function_name()

Comment: Hey Jamal, I would kindly share my  [repo](https://github.com/huxaiphaer/starwars_challenge) link and have a look, please clone the project and try to see what exactly happens.

The solution you gave me didn't work.

Comment: Did you get any clue ?

Comment: @IdrisStack I'm at work now, I'll fix it tonight and tell you what's solution